# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException while running unit test when using @Configuration

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit

This issue is linked to my previous one at [Spring @WebMvcTest with @EnableJpa* annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467132/spring-webmvctest-with-enablejpa-annotation).

So I moved @Enable* to `@Configuration` class but it breaks my other unit test classes, and that's why I had my previous question. I guess I didn't explain quite clearly before, so I try my best to do so in this question.

As seen in the answer, to resolve the error of "At least one JPA metamodel must be present!" when running test with `@WebMvcTest`, it is to move `@Enable*` annotation to a `@Configuration` class. While that did resolve the issue, many other issue occured in the other test class which I am not sure why it breaks those.

From what I see now, it breaks two type of test class. 1. Mail (`@SpringBootTest`) test class and 2. Repository (`@DataJpaTest`) test class.

Before I proceed, these are my snippet of the classes I think are relevant.

**Main**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**AppConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationConfiguration {

}
```

**AccountServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

    private final AccountRepository accountRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private final ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;
```

**MailServiceImpl**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

    private final JavaMailSender mailSender;
    private final MailTemplateContentBuilderImpl mailTemplateContentBuilder;
```

1. Mail (`@SpringBootTest`) test class

`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    private GreenMail smtpServer;

    @Before
    // Removed below
```

`

And the error came as

```
2018-07-27 22:18:23.519 ERROR 7928 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.sample.account.AccountServiceImpl required a bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' in your configuration.

2018-07-27 22:18:23.523 ERROR 7928 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@424e1977] to prepare test instance [com.sample.mail.MailServiceTest@6497b078]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountController' defined in file [Z:\Development\Spring\sample\target\classes\com\sample\account\AccountController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl' defined in file [Z:\Development\Spring\sample\target\classes\com\sample\account\AccountServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:139) ~[spring-boot-test-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountServiceImpl' defined in file [Z:\Development\Spring\sample\target\classes\com\sample\account\AccountServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:503) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

2. Repository (`@DataJpaTest`) test class.

`

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class AccountRespositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private AccountRepository accountRespository;
```

`

And the error came as (see) https://pastebin.com/WBMccZUu. (as it's too long to include)

Remember that this two type of error wouldn't occur if I did not move to use `@Configuration` class. But if I don't move to `@Configuration` for `@Enable*` annotation, then the JPA metamodel error would occur.

<strike>My guess for the Repository issue, it couldn't see the `@Configuration` class? However, I tried to create the same `@Configuration` class using `@TestConfiguration` in my /src/test folder and called in `ApplicationConfigurationTest.class`.</strike>

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationConfigurationTest {

}
```

And inside my Repository class, I did a `@Import(ApplicationConfigurationTest.class)` and it wouldn't work as well. It complains another issue though, of same nature.

```
2018-07-27 22:57:51.951 ERROR 11852 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@3c407114] to prepare test instance [com.sample.account.AccountRespositoryTest@4fb0f2b9]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sample.account.AccountRespositoryTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'accountRespository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1350) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:401) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460) [.cp/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sample.account.AccountRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1509) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

To be clear, this is what I did. I didn't meant that I did on the actual Repository class. It was on the test class.

```
@TestConfiguration
@Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class ApplicationConfigurationTest {

}
```

I also tried.

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationConfigurationTest {

}

@DataJpaTest
@Import(ApplicationConfigurationTest.class) 
// Tried this as well, doesn't work
// @Import(ApplicationConfiguration.class)
public class AccountRespositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

But it still gives the same NoSuchBeanDefinitionException as before.

Kinda of clueless here. What should be the right way to do to ensure that my test can run properly.

Thank you. and let me know if I missed out any information.

Comment: `@Import` on a repository class is pretty much useless. Also you cannot reference test classes from your main classes. The `@Import` should be on your `@TestConfiguration` class (to reuse your existing configuration) or place it on your test class.

Comment: Also you would need to define `basePackages` to scan to the `@EnableJpaRepository` annotation (depending on where you put it).

Comment: I did the @Import correctly, I think. I have updated the post, please take a look. Correct me if I did it wrongly. Do you mean Component scan like > ComponentScan("com.sample")? I tried to add in the AccountRespositoryTest class as well, and it gave the same error (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I have managed to resolve my issue, and I actually did came quite close to it previously with *@M. Deinum* comment.

It's quite simple actually.

As mentioned previously, I had a `@TestConfiguration` created. But I missed out to use basePackages, or rather I used it wrongly. So I was reading [spring-data query method documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods), I came across this portion:

> Also, note that the JavaConfig variant does not configure a package
>   explicitly, because the package of the annotated class is used by
>   default. **To customize the package to scan, use one of the basePackage…
>   attributes of the data-store-specific repository’s
>   @Enable${store}Repositories-annotation.**

And that's where it hits me. Hence, I added in the **basePackages** in `@TestConfiguration` to scan which I believe that because my test was in a different package, and when you are doing a `@DataJpaTest`, it wouldn't pick up the classes from other package (correct me if I'm wrong).

And then if you see [Spring Auto-configured Tests Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html), it also states (which I knew):

> It often helps to load only the parts of the configuration that are
>   required to test a “slice” of your application. For example, you might
>   want to test that Spring MVC controllers are mapping URLs correctly,
>   and you do not want to involve database calls in those tests, or you
>   might want to test JPA entities, and you are not interested in the web
>   layer when those tests run.

So with that, using `@DataJpaTest`, you need to specifically `@import` the `@TestConfiguration`.

```
@TestConfiguration
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.sample", repositoryFactoryBeanClass = EnversRevisionRepositoryFactoryBean.class)
public class ApplicationConfigurationTest {

}

@DataJpaTest
@Import(ApplicationConfigurationTest.class) 
public class AccountRespositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;
```

And as I suspected, this also resolved the **MailServiceTest Class** issue I was facing as well.

It's a good lesson learnt, and pays well to read more carefully in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Use **classed = {SampleApplication.class}** in SpringBootTest
so SampleApplication will help to create all dependencies.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SampleApplication.class}, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MailServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    private GreenMail smtpServer;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it doesn't work. I have also tried using ContextConfiguration("SampleApplication.class") as well.

Comment: can you add poc of it in github and share the link ?

Comment: I have added, please pull from https://github.com/bwgjoseph/beanexception-poc. I have added description in the README.md, thank you.