# No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available in RestController unsit test with Junit 5

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5

I am getting 'No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available' in my junit5 test class even when i am mocking the service layer class.
My understanding is if service layer is mocked, it should not look for actual jpa implementation. I am not understanding what i am missing. My application runs fine with JPA, only problem i am facing in the unit testing with @WebMvcTest

**spring boot application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication(
    scanBasePackages = {"com.testapp.rest.auth"})
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping(
      value = "/testRest/auth",
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<ResObj> testValid(
      @RequestBody ReqObj reqObj, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders headerSet)
      throws SampleTechnicalException {

    ResObj response = authServ.authorize(reqObj);

    if (response.isSuccess()) {
      log.info("Request processed successfully. response : {}", response.isSuccess());
      return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    } else {
      log.error(
          "Request couldn't be processed successfully. response : {}",
          response.isSuccess());
      return new ResponseEntity<ResObj>(response, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
  }
```

**service**

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AuthSerive {

  private SampleRepository1 sampleRepository1;

  private SampleRepository2 sampleRepository2;

  public ResObj authorize(ReqObj reqObj) throws SampleTechnicalException {


    if (reqObj == null) {
      throw new SampleTechnicalException("throw exception");
    }
    ..
    
}
```

**Controller Test class**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = AuthController.class)
class AuthControllerTest {

  @MockBean AuthSerive authServ;

  @Autowired private MockMvc mockMvc;

  

  @Test
  void testAuthSample() throws Exception {
    String jsonreq =
        "{ \"field1\":\"\", \"field2\":\"x\", \"field3\":\"\", \"field4\":\"\", \"field5\":"y", \"field6\":\"z\", \"field7\":\"x\" }";
    ResObj mockResponse =
        ResObj.builder().authSuccess(true).errorMessage(null).build();

    ReqObj mockTestObj=
        ReqObj.builder().field2("x").field5("y").field6("z").field7("x").build();

    Mockito.when(authServ.authorize(mockTestObj)).thenReturn(mockResponse);

    mockMvc
        .perform(post("/api/testRest/auth").contentType("application/json").content(jsonreq))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

     
  }
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8:18.3.0.0'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation group: 'org.springdoc', name: 'springdoc-openapi-ui', version: '1.5.8'

    implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context'

    testCompile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-all"
    }

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

**error**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'SampleRepository1' defined in com.testapp.rest.auth.repository.SampleRepository1 defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#47a7c93e' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47a7c93e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1689)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:925)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:782)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:774)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#47a7c93e': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
    ... 87 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
```

Answer (score 6):

I understood the problem as @EnableJpaRepositories was with bootapllication class , it was trying to load it. solution is bootapplication class should have only @springbootapplication annotation and any other configuration can be move out to separate config file with @configuration annotation. I found it here
[Spring @WebMvcTest with @EnableJpa* annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467132/spring-webmvctest-with-enablejpa-annotation)

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming as we've added  @EnableJpaRepositories at root level.

```
    @SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = {"com.testapp.rest.auth"})
    @EnableJpaRepositories
    public class SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication {
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication.class, args);
      }
    }
```

instead remove that and write as below:

```
    @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.testapp.rest.auth"})
   
    public class SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication {
    
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleAuthorizationServiceApplication.class, args);
      }
    }
```

Further we can create a configuration class in any suitable package and add below code in that, here basePackages is where your repository(SampleRepository1) file is present:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = RefreshRepositoryImpl.class,
       basePackages = "com.testapp.persistence")
    public class RepositoryConfig {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as previous answer said, `EnableJpaRepositories` need to be removed.
Second, what if after it is removed, your `WebMvcTest` request the repository interfaces? The answer is to add `@MockBean` in your `WebMvcTest` for all the `@Service`s and `@Repository`s